# Inherit, Repository, MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a StartController that contains a list of movies in a repository. I want to use that list, not only in StartController but in my GenreController but I can't figure out how.
This is my StartController:

```
namespace IMDB
{
    public class StartController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Start
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var movies = GetMoviesFromRepository();

            return View(movies);
        }
        // GET: Details

        public ActionResult Movie(int id)
        {
            var allMovies = GetMoviesFromRepository();
            var movie = allMovies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MovieID.Equals(id));

            return View(movie);
        }

        private List<Movie> GetMoviesFromRepository()
        {

            var movies = new List<Movie>();

            var movie1 = new Movie();
            movie1.MovieID = 1;
            movie1.Title = "Terminator";
            movie1.Genre = "Comedy";
            movie1.Year = 1984;
            movie1.Country = "America";
            movie1.Picture = "http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/tvdatabase/images/8/89/Terminator_(1984).jpg";
            movies.Add(movie1);

            var movie2 = new Movie();
            movie2.MovieID = 2;
            movie2.Title = "Terminator 2: Judgement Day";
            movie2.Genre = "Romantic";
            movie2.Year = 1991;
            movie2.Country = "America";
            movie2.Picture = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/85/Terminator2poster.jpg";
            movies.Add(movie2);

            return movies;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the GenreController where I want to access the list from StartController:

```
namespace IMDB.Controllers
{
    public class GenreController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Genre
        public ActionResult Genre(string genre)
        {
            var allGenres = GetMoviesFromRepository();
            // Some code goes here

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this isn't working. But I can't figure out how to get my list to work in GenreController.

Comment: Best way is to make `GetMoviesFromRepository` separately and use it from both controller, it's make more sense!

Comment: Ok, I see. How would I actually do that though? And how do I use it from both controllers? (total newb here)

Comment: Hey, sorry but running busy,  You can add new class library and add your class over there,and add your `GetMoviesFromRepository`in that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Div is talking about:

Extract the movie repository logic out of your controller and into its own class. It's purpose will be for retrieving your Movies.

```
    public class MovieRepository {
        public List<Movie> GetMoviesFromRepository()
        {
            var movies = new List<Movie>();

            var movie1 = new Movie();
            movie1.MovieID = 1;
            movie1.Title = "Terminator";
            movie1.Genre = "Comedy";
            movie1.Year = 1984;
            movie1.Country = "America";
            movie1.Picture = "http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/tvdatabase/images/8/89/Terminator_(1984).jpg";
            movies.Add(movie1);

            var movie2 = new Movie();
            movie2.MovieID = 2;
            movie2.Title = "Terminator 2: Judgement Day";
            movie2.Genre = "Romantic";
            movie2.Year = 1991;
            movie2.Country = "America";
            movie2.Picture = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/85/Terminator2poster.jpg";
            movies.Add(movie2);

            return movies;
        }
    }
```

Then in your controllers, add a constructor that initializes a private variable that will hold your MovieRepository. Then, anywhere you want to retrieve your movie collection, just call movieRepository.GetMoviesFromRepository().

```
        public class StartController : Controller {
            private readonly MovieRepository movieRepository;

            public StartController()
            {
                this.movieRepository = new MovieRepository();
            }

            // GET: Start
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var movies = movieRepository.GetMoviesFromRepository();

                return View(movies);
            }
            // GET: Details

            public ActionResult Movie(int id)
            {
                var allMovies = movieRepository.GetMoviesFromRepository();
                var movie = allMovies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MovieID.Equals(id));

                return View(movie);
            }

        }
```